# Order confirmation mail not sent

Tags: magento2, email, cron, order-email, order-confirmation

So i have a slightly big problem and would need a solution fast for my website.

Only the order confirmation/invoice confirmation etc etc mails are not being sent! All the other mails (including order update mails) are working.

Things that i already have done :

- checked together with my host if the cron jobs are running
- disabling all external modules and even uninstalling some
- going to developer mode and back , redeploying static files
- checking for log files etc (no errors)

It seems like for some reason magento 2 says 'mail sent' but doesn't queue it or anything. I dunno.

Anyone an idea? I know its not a lot of information to go on but thats all related i can give because all the other things i did or mentioned didn't return any information.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe a small comment : This is occuring since i went from developer mode to production mode

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by deleting orders (actual orders, not order queue) from the cron_schedule in the database and putting my website 'asynchronous sending' on disabled

Comment: Versdivers, what did you exactly deleted? I'm facing the same problem, sometimes (not always) mails are not send

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this setting in Admin:

```
Store > Configration > Sales > Sales Emails > General Settings > Asynchronous sending >
```

If this is enabled Magento instead of sending the email when the order is placed, adds an entry in a queue table (core_email_queue), and then a cron job comes, reads all the entries from the queue and sends the emails.

Somehow if the cron is not run or for some other reason the emails are not sent.

I would suggest to set it to disabled.

People recommend this option to set to enabled. I am looking for an answer as to which is that cron which reads the entries and sends emails.